# Unresolved Reference in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I have made a function named `double()`. When calling it, it gives an error of `Unresolved reference`.

```
val result = double(2)
print(result)

fun double(x: Int): Int {
    return 2 * x
}
```

Comment: side-note : you can also write this as : `fun double(x: Int) = 2 * x`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using locally defined functions, you have to declare it before using:

```
fun main() {
    fun double(x: Int): Int {
        return 2 * x
    }

    val result = double(2)
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: @IhteSham You should select it as the answer if you found this helpful.

Comment: @AndreiTanana its not working because the `double()` method u are calling **is inside** main !

Comment: @SantanuSur yep, I know. Some guy told me that he can use a local function before decaration. Now his comment is removed

Answer (score 2):

Try to call the fun double *inside main* :

**Also make sure `double(param : Int)` is outside main else it will give error**

```
 fun main() {
    val result = double(2)
    print(result)
 }

 fun double(x: Int): Int = 2 * x
```